# PHP Contact form not working on Network Solutions

Tags: php, forms

http://makeupbysherry.com/contact.php

Contact form that is using php doesn't seem to be working and not getting emails from the form. I've tried a few different emails, and the host is on Network Solutions. I had this site on a test server on GoDaddy and now it doesn't work on Netsol.

Not sure what the issue is, this site was transferred over from windows to unix hosting this morning and seems to be up and running except this. Any idea what's happening? Thanks!

Bryan

Update:

```
    <?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "bryan@bryankremkau.com";

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = check_input($_POST['name'], "Enter your name");
$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
$subject  = check_input($_POST['subject'], "Write a subject");
$message = check_input($_POST['message'], "Write your message");
$check .= implode(', ', $_POST['check']);



/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* If URL is not valid set $website to empty */
if (!preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i", $website))
{
    $website = '';
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "Hello!

Your contact form has been submitted by:

Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject

Message: $message

Description: $check

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.php');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: try posting the code, we can't tell otherwise.

Comment: Still trying to get someone to help me out because the php.ini stuff doesn't seem to be working. I've tried that and still not getting the messages. Does having header includes affect this at all? The Netsol guy seemed to think so...

Answer (score 2):

On Unix PHP uses sendmail to send email.

Since you're on a Unix system you'll want to set `sendmail_path` in your php.ini file and make sure you have sendmail installed.

Create a new file in the cgi-bin directory called php.ini with one line:
`sendmail path = /usr/sbin/sendmail`

Comment: Any chance you can help me out with how to do that? I don't have a clue haha

Answer (score 0):

You usually need to configure your PHP contact form with the SMTP connection details.  Usually a username and password along with the SMTP server name are required so that the script authenticates before sending out e-mail.  This is enabled to prevent spammers from utilizing the mail server.

Comment: Not sure how to fix it in the current code that I have though. I don't really know php.